# What is Bnd @Attribute annotation for?

Tags: osgi, declarative-services, bnd

When looking at annotations in `aQute.bnd.annotation.component` package in bndlib-1.50.0, there is one not listed at http://www.aqute.biz/Blog/20091020 or http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Components: `@Attribute`. What is it used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a mistake to me. According to the git history (https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/commits/master/biz.aQute.bndlib/src/aQute/bnd/annotation/component/Attribute.java) there was just one commit to add it, and it's clearly incomplete due to the unused inner class C.

grepcode finds no usages anywhere (http://grepcode.com/search/usages?type=type&id=repo1.maven.org%24maven2@biz.aQute%24bndlib@1.50.0@aQute%24bnd%24annotation%24component@Attribute&k=u)

Answer (score 2):

It has no current function ...